# Theorems in groff

Tags: groff

Is there a way in `groff -ms` to automatically number environments? As an example, here are two theorems I'd like to number 1.1 and 2.1.

```
.TL
Lorem ipsum
.NH
Introduction
\# First thm
.PP
.B Theorem .
Consectetur sed sunt nulla aute dolor elit ut quis.
.EQ
e sup {i pi} + 1 = 0
.EN
\# End of the first thm
.NH
Main result
.PP
.B Theorem .
Magna dolore.
.EQ
e sup {i tau} = 1
.EN
```

Comment: Could you say what part of the document you consider a theorem that should be numbered? It's unclear whether you are referring to the already numbered section (`.NH`), the bold text (`.B`) or the equations themselves (`.EQ`).

Comment: I added comments, a theorem is a whole paragraph with a bold title, a text and possibly equations.

Comment: sure - you could write macros to encapsulate the behavior you want, but for that, you need a *tutorial* (off-topic here).

Comment: @ThomasDickey It's not that different from "I have _this_ code that almost works, and now I want to do _this_ with it". It's not off-topic.

Comment: It may be complicated to do, but the request is simple: number paragraphs starting with a particular text. I don't see where the off-topic is.

Comment: The issue is that, as far as I know, the `ms` macros do not provide numbered displays (what you call "environment"). So any solution to this would need to involve some quite complicated `roff` macro coding.  Numbering the _equations_ (manually) is easy enough (just add the number after the `.EQ` request).  ("Complicated" since it's not most people would know much about)

Comment: I can't write the numbers by hand, adding a section or a theorem would force me to change them all. However, I understand that you have to work at a low level, I thought there was a native solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have looked at `.NH 2` to give you 2nd level numbered headings, and that is not what is wanted, you can use your own number register, as shown in the man page `.IP` indented paragraph example.

Add to the start the definition and initialisation of your number register (starts at 0, increment by 1)

```
.nr mytheorem 0 1
```

then whereever you use it as

```
\n+[mytheorem]
```

it will be incremented and replaced by the current value. Eg use

```
.PP 
\*[SN]\n+[mytheorem]
.B Theorem .
```

where `SN` is the section number (from `.NH`).
You can reset the register by giving the `.nr` definition again.
You can put the above into a macro at the start:

```
.de myTHEOREM
.PP
\\*[SN]\\n+[mytheorem]
.B Theorem .
..
```

and call it each time:

```
.myTHEOREM
Magna dolore.
.EQ
e sup {i tau} = 1
.EN
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect